# Run testSuite in katalon using Jenkins throwing "Access denied"

Tags: jenkins, katalon-studio

When I build My KatalonTestSuite using Jenkins in windows 10 I am getting below error message.

```
Started by user Forough Omidvar
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\KatalonTestSuiteRun
[KatalonTestSuiteRun] $ "C:\Program Files\Git\bin" -xe C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins7833660586059993479.sh
Access is denied
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Git\bin" (in directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\KatalonTestSuiteRun"): CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:250)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:219)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:937)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:455)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:109)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:66)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1853)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:427)
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

It seems Jenkin users don’t have the right permission to access the files but I have permission via windows/Security.